# C Issues between OS X versions Causes Undefined Behavior

Tags: c, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

## EDIT

I have tried to initialize `c` as `char c[2] = {'\0'};` with the same results, and changed `strncpy((char *)c, tmp, 1);` to `strncpy(c, tmp, 1);` also with the same results.

Also changed `strcat(tmp, (char *)c)` to `strcat(tmp, c)` with same outcomes.

I also attempted to use `memset()` on c, with null bytes, with the same results. It still performs as intended on 10.10.5, but performs with also adding `??s?` to the string on 10.11.6.

---

I have been practicing some C, and decided to write a text parser at work. It reads data from a file and performs operations on it based on different arguments passed to it. One option is to have it convert all text in a file to Pig Latin, which works fine on OS X 10.10.5, but I showed my girlfriend at home (OS X 10.11.6) (who is helping me to migrate from easy scripting languages Python/JS) and it started to put random bytes between characters in the same spot on each word. Here is the code and output on my 10.10 machine.

**main.c**

```
#include "parser.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2){err("Program Requires at Least One Argument.");}
    if(argc > 6){err("Too many arguments.");}

    int i = 1;      // for indexing args (don't care about arg 0)

    /* loop over the arguments to find any parameters
    we don't look at last argument, as it should be
    the file name */
    for(i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-v") == 0) {v = 1;}
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0) {p = 1;}
        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-c") == 0) {c = 1;}
        else {err("Invalid Argument.");}
    }

    strcpy(flnm, argv[argc-1]);

    parse(flnm);

    return 0;
}
```

**parser.c**

```
void parse(const char *fn)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fn, "r");
    if(!f) {err("File does not exist.");}

    if(v == 1) {
        while(xfscanf(f) != 0) {
            vwlCnt(buff);
            printf("%s\n", buff);
        }

        printf("File \"%s\" contains %d vowels.\n", fn, v_cnt);
    }

    if(p == 1) {
        FILE *fp = fopen("out.txt", "w+");
        if(!fp) {err("File write error.");}

        while(xfscanf(f) != 0) {
            pigLat(buff);
            fputs(buff, fp);
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

    if(c == 1 && v + p != 2) {
        if(p == 1) {FILE *fp = fopen("out.txt", "r"); cat(fp);}
        else {cat(f);}
    }

    fclose(f);
}

void pigLat(char *str)
{
    int con = 0;
    char *c[1];
    char *tmp = TEMP(str);

    switch(tmp[0]) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            con = 0;
            break;
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            con = 0;
            break;
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            con = 0;
            break;
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            con = 0;
            break;
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            con = 0;
            break;
        default:
            con = 1;
            break;
    }

    if(con == 1) {
        printf("%c\n", tmp[0]);
        strncpy((char *)c, tmp, 1);

        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(tmp); i++) {
            tmp[i] = tmp[i+1];
        }

        strcat(tmp, (char *)c);
        strcat(tmp, "ay ");

        strcpy(buff, tmp);
    } else {strcat(tmp, "ay "); strcpy(buff, tmp);}

    printf("%s\n", tmp);
}
```

**parser.h**

```
#ifndef __parser_h__
#define __parser_h__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int p;              // pig latin argument;
int v;              // vowel count argument
int c;              // cat arg
int v_cnt;          // vowel count
char vwl;           // vowel char
char flnm[64];      // file name
char buff[32];      // file scan buffer


void err(const char *msg);      // error function
char *newTemp(char *str);       // creates a 32B temp pointer on heap
int  xfscanf(FILE *f);          // simple fscan
void cat(FILE *f);
void parse(const char *fn);     // file parsing function
void vwlCnt(char *str);         // counts vowels in string
void pigLat(char *str);         // pig latinize string

#define TEMP(X) newTemp(X)

#endif
```

*input file*

> With less than one week of competition left in the 2016 Rio Olympic Games, empty stadium seats seem to be stealing the spotlight away from some of the world's most decorated athletes.So far 88% of the more than 6 million total tickets have been sold in Rio de Janeiro, Olympic organizers said Wednesday. That's less than the London Games in 2012 and the Beijing Games in 2008, which both sold 96% of their tickets. But it's much better than the 2004 Games in Athens, where just 67% of the event tickets were purchased.Attendance has been strong for marquee events such as gymnastics and sports in which Brazil has been expected to excel, such as soccer and beach volleyball. Still, large swaths of empty seats can be seen at many venues, most notably at the track and field stadium.

**Output**

> ithWay esslay hantay oneay eekway ofay ompetitiioncay eftlay inay hetay 0162ay ioRay Olympicay ames,Gay emptyay tadiumsay eatssay eemsay otay ebay tealingsay hetay potlighttsay awayay romfay omesay ofay hetay orld'sway ostmay ecorateddday athletes.ay oSay arfay 8%8ay ofay hetay oremay hantay 6ay illionmay otaltay icketstay avehay eenbay oldsay inay ioRay eday aneiro,Jay Olympicay organizersay aidsay ednesdayy.Way hat'sTay esslay hantay hetay ondonLay amesGay inay 0122ay anday hetay eijingBay amesGay inay 008,2ay hichway othbay oldsay 6%9ay ofay heirtay ickets.tay utBay it'say uchmay etterbay hantay hetay 0042ay amesGay inay Athens,ay hereway ustjay 7%6ay ofay hetay eventay icketstay ereway urchasedd.pay Attendanceay ashay eenbay trongsay orfay arqueemay eventsay uchsay asay ymnasticcsgay anday portssay inay hichway razilBay ashay eenbay expecteday otay excel,ay uchsay asay occersay anday eachbay olleyballl.vay till,Say argelay wathssay ofay emptyay eatssay ancay ebay eensay atay anymay enues,vay ostmay otablynay atay hetay racktay anday ieldfay tadium.say

On 10.11.6, for example, `seatssay` ends up as `seats?c?ay` or any other random few bytes. I am not sure the cause of this, I tried altering some code when I noticed the behavior but was unable to find a solution, I only made it worse.

I didn't include the entire `parser.c` file, as the other functions are unrelated. `xfscanf` simply performs `fscanf` and returns a 0 if `EOF` is reached. `*newTemp` creates a temporary string from the string passed to it, returning a pointer to a new copy of that string, so that the original is not mutilated by the vowel counting function (I replace the vowels with X's in that function).

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated with why this is behaving as it is!

Comment: And the debugger is your friend, of course..

Comment: Kind of a follow on to Mark's comment, why is `c` a 1-element array of pointer to `char`?  What is `c`'s purpose in this code?

Comment: @JohnBode Since the length of a word is unknown, as all words have different length I have to use strcat to append the character to the end of the string, and in order to use strcat, you have to use a string literal to append. So c is an array of characters in order to use it in appending via strcat. Unless a char can be typecasted all the same...

Comment: @spectre-d: "So c is an array of characters in order to use it in appending via strcat" - no, `c` is a 1-element array of *pointer to `char`* that hasn't been initialized to point anywhere meaningful, not an array of `char`.  You're (ab)using it as an array of `char` when you do the cast to `char *` in the `strncat` and `strcpy` calls.

Comment: @JohnBode, Right, thank you. I attempted to initialize it as `" "`, and use `memmove` but that made the output worse. What would be the best course of action to reach the end goal that I am already achieving on 10.10? I am really just unsure of the difference in the output between the systems, unless it's a big difference in the compiler version or something that I do not understand fully, yet.

Comment: Error messages of the form "Error opening file" that do not contain a path to the file in question will be the primary cause of the end of civilization.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The end-user isn't exactly *existent*. While I do see your point, if I hadn't needed to ask for help with this issue, this code wouldn't have seen the outside of my drive, so as far as necessitating very explicit error messages, I do not see a need when using it for myself. That said, in the case of a situation embedded nested deep within the program, I'd probably write something far more explicit. But, as I am not working on a team or with anyone else, what works for me is all that matters. Oh, and I identified the root issue to be related to Google Drive.

Comment: First problem:  variable declarations in the header file, rather than in (for instance) the parse.c file (and if needed, `extern` statements in the header file.

Comment: Second problem: comparison between signed and unsigned integers in this line: `for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(tmp); i++) {`

Comment: third problem: in C, all variable names beginning with two underscores or underscore followed by capital letter are reserved for the environment.  So the lines: `#ifndef __parser_h__
#define __parser_h__` are against the rules (though they will probably compile)  Strongly suggest dropping the leading underscores

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability, 1) use meaningful variable names.  The names should indicate usage or content (or better, both).  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: forth problem:  regarding this line: `for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(tmp); i++)`  `tmp` is a pointer,  A pointer is (depending on the underlying architecture) either 4 or 8 bytes.  so the code is not (necessarily) moving the full word (it will only move the 2nd through 5th (or 9th) bytes

Comment: fifth problem: from the code, there is the strong hint that 'cat()` does not close the file it is working with.  However, at the end of the `parse()` function, the file pointer `f` is closed but not `fp`

Comment: the posted code uses several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  for instance, 32 and 64.  strongly suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names (via an `enum` or `#define` statements) then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: sixth problem:  according to the comments, the function 'newTemp()` performs a `malloc()`.   However, the resulting pointer to allocated memory is never passed to `free()`, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: regarding this line: `if(argc < 2){err("Program Requires at Least One Argument.");}`  that is not quite true.  if the only argument is the file name, then the posted code does little to nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemingly was the result of Google Drive not syncing correctly after making the changes suggested by users in the comments. The code works now, using these changes:

---

**Restructured `pigLat` to use a While-Loop rather than For-Loop**

```
    int i = 0;
    while(tmp[i] != '\0') {
        tmp[i] = tmp[i+1];
        i++;
    }
```

> Ensures that null bytes don't end up being moved to where they should not be moved, and sizeof(tmp) is not going to return the actual size, only 32B as is defined

**Initialized c**

```
char c[2] = {'\0'};
```

Program now working as intended.

Comment: this is still wrong.  the statement: `sizeof(tmp)` returns the size of the pointer: `tmp`, not the number of bytes in the string.   To get the number of bytes in a string use `strlen(tmp)`